# 'Owning library is missing' error when saving LabVIEW 2016 OOP project to LabVIEW 8.5

Tags: labview

I am developing a LabVIEW controlled experiment using version 2016, but I need to transfer it to LabVIEW 8.5. When saving the project to version 8.5 I lose the ability to work with my classes.

I made a simple test:

[image: screenshot]

I do not understand which library I'm missing. What could be the solution to this problem?

Comment: What happens if you start a brand new OOP project in LabVIEW 8.5, open and modify it in 2016, then save it back to 8.5 again - does it work, and if so can you figure out what is different in the layout or setup of the two projects? Other than that I would suggest asking this on the NI forums.

Comment: @nekomatic, if it was done in 8.5 first, the same problem by opening it with 2016. But only with VIs of classes.

Comment: I haven't really used LabVIEW OOP much so assuming you're following the procedure in http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/lvhowto/saving_for_the_previous_ve/ and have checked the 'Save for Previous Warning Summary' for any warnings as described, I can't think of any further suggestions. I'm sure a good question on the NI site will get you an answer though.

Comment: @nekomatic, they already proposed me to develop everything in 8.5:) But nevertheless I think I found a solution. I just need to have two sets of classes and VI done in 2016 and 8.5. And when is needed just to switch between them - simply replacing them one by another, while working with 2016 or 8.5 LabVIEW^) It sounds stupid, what it works for me at this moment. Hope there is a better solution.